# Vue.js - How do I display an object in an array, that the array is inside of an object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display an array of messages (objects). The array of messages is inside of a conversation (main object). However, I am seeing the data show up in the Vue developer tools when I press expand, but I can't figure out how to show the array in the viewport.

Thank you!

[image: Here is some photos of my code and the Vue dev tools, after I press expand.]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<span> conversation.recipientID </span>`?

Comment: Can you copy the code in snippets here, it'll be helpful and easier to debug.

Comment: `photos of my code` pixel heaps? Don't.

Comment: please never post screenshots of the relevant code or error messages, copy them into your post *as text* instead and format them as code. There are myriads of reasons to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input v-model="message[0].payload">` doesn't seem correct. `message` in that context is not an array and thus there is no `message[0]`.

Could that be the answer?

Also you are referencing `this.conversation` in your JavaScript, but you also create the variable `conversation` in the `v-for="conversation in conversations"` in your template code. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The message[0] was something I was messing with, thanks for pointing out to fix that. Also, the main issue was that I was referencing this.conversation, rather than the conversation variable that was fed in through the fetchMessage(conversation) function. Thank you, maxpaj!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should do

```
...v-model="message.payload"...
```

Also Shouldn't it be `<span> conversation.recipientID </span>`?